# General solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2e^{x-y}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I am learning about general solutions to differential equations and would like to ask whether my solution is mathematically correct.

I was asked to find the general solution to the differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2e^{x-y}$$

So I did the following -

$$\int e^y dy = 2\int e^x dx$$
$$e^y = 2 e^x + C $$
$$y = \ln (2 e^x + C) $$

Now, my book says that the solution in the form $y = f(x)$ is $y = \ln (2 e^x + C) $.

However, I progressed further and did the following:

$$y = \ln (2 e^x + C) $$
$$ = \ln (e^{{x}^{2}} + C) $$
$$y = x^2 + C' $$

where $C'$ is a modified constant from the original constant $C$.

Is this an acceptable solution?

Comment: No, not acceptable, as you are using wrong property of exponential and logarithm.

Comment: @Idonknow so where did I go wrong?

Comment: $2e^x \neq e^{x^2}$

Comment: @Idonknow so it is not to simplify further beyond $y = \ln (2 e^x + C) $?

Comment: The problem is that we have nothing to simplify beyond your mentioned equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You went wrong in two places.  First you replaced $2e^x$ with $e^{x^2}$.  It seems you were thinking about $2 \ln a= \ln (a^2)$, but note that the $2$ is outside the log here.  Second, you are thinking that $e^{x^2}=(e^x)^2$, but the convention is that $e^{x^2}=e^{(x^2)}$ because you can replace $(e^x)^2$ by $e^{2x}$

Comment: Brilliant answer - I will take note of this!

Answer (score 0):

Note this inequality: $$2e^x\neq e^{x^2}$$